# Unable to compile jsp files using GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, salesforce

I'm trying to deploy an App for the first time on the App Engine and i'm getting an error saying "com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.". Anyone have any ideas how can i fix this. I've set up eclipse to point to JDK1.6.0_17. I'm trying to integrate OAuth with salesforce and GAE using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo having App Engine SDK 1.7. The problem is that application was written in jdk 1.5 and I have to make it deploy in jdk 1.6. I have used 5 helper jar files as: commons-codec-1.6.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, oauth-1.4.jar, partner-18.jar, wsc-gae-16_0.jar. The partner jar contains: com.sforce.sobject.SObject.class which is to be used to compile jsp files.
Its showing the error as:

```
    Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
Jul 11, 2012 10:20:18 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Error compiling file: C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java     [javac] Compiling 1 source file
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:6: package com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject does not exist
    [javac] import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:6: package com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject does not exist
    [javac] import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SObject
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.accounts_jsp
    [javac]   SObject[] accounts = (SObject[])request.getAttribute("accounts");
    [javac]   ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SObject
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.accounts_jsp
    [javac]   SObject[] accounts = (SObject[])request.getAttribute("accounts");
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:69: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SObject
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.accounts_jsp
    [javac]  for (SObject account : accounts) { 
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] Note: C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 4 errors

Jul 11, 2012 10:20:18 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Javac exception
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:933)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:226)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:18)
Jul 11, 2012 10:20:18 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Environment: Compile: javaFileName=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java
    classpath=/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/google_sql.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\el-api.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\servlet-api.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr107cache-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr107cache-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar
    cp=/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/google_sql.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\el-api.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\servlet-api.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr107cache-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\impl\appengine-api-labs.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\impl\appengine-api-stubs.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\impl\appengine-api.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\impl\appengine-local-runtime.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\impl\google_sql.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\el-api.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar
    cp=D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\servlet-api.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.0.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr107cache-1.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.0.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr107cache-1.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar
    cp=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar
    work dir=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes
    extension dir=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\jre\lib\ext;C:\windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
    srcDir=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes
    compiler=extJavac
   compilerTargetVM=1.5
   compilerSourceVM=1.5
    include=org/apache/jsp/accounts_jsp.java


Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:6: package com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject does not exist
    [javac] import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;
    [javac]                                       ^


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:6: package com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject does not exist
    [javac] import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;
    [javac]                                       ^


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SObject
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.accounts_jsp
    [javac]   SObject[] accounts = (SObject[])request.getAttribute("accounts");
    [javac]   ^


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SObject
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.accounts_jsp
    [javac]   SObject[] accounts = (SObject[])request.getAttribute("accounts");
    [javac]                         ^


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java:69: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SObject
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.accounts_jsp
    [javac]  for (SObject account : accounts) { 
    [javac]       ^


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] Note: C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 4 errors



An error occurred at line: 20 in the generated java file
Jul 11, 2012 10:20:18 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Javac exception
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:933)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:226)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:18)


An error occurred at line: 20 in the generated java file
Jul 11, 2012 10:20:18 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
SEVERE: Environment: Compile: javaFileName=C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\accounts_jsp.java


An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    classpath=/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar;/D:/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/lib/impl/google_sql.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\el-api.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar;D:\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared\servlet-api.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr107cache-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg54831.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\T....... and so on

Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\Astrea\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy54830.log
```

$Any ideas why this is happening?
the file i'm using is: 
accounts.jsp

```
<%@ page import="com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject" %>

<%  
  SObject[] accounts = (SObject[])request.getAttribute("accounts");
%>

<%@ include
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the extra jars are in `WEB-INF\lib` directory (or make sure that your IDE copies them there).

Comment: yeah all the jars are in WEB-INF\lib directory and eclipse is copying right into lib. I think if I try to deploy this app using Jdk 1.5 will solve my problem but that too is generating problem, eclipse ide doesn't open when some plugins like google app engine is installed. Whether I should support jdk 1.5 or i should try to resolve the above problem. please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

try this :
may be  it work

```
Add -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin\javaw.exe to my eclipse.ini.
Ensure that the JDK is in my project's build path and not the jre.
Add the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin\ to the PATH for Environment Variable.
```

change JAVA_HOME path to JDK from JRE and make sure JAVA_HOME\bin is included in PATH. Then, restart Eclipse.

and even if problem persist 
build path for that package.